# If $G = \{ q \in \mathbb{Q} \ | \ |q| \geq 1 \ \ \text{or} \ q = 0\}$ and $+ : G \times G \to G$, show that $+$ is associative on $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

> If $G = \{ q \in \mathbb{Q} \ | \ |q| \geq 1  \  \text{or}  \  q = 0 \}$ and $+ : G \times G \to G$, show that $+$ is associative on $G$

Intuitively this seems like a very very simple problem, yet it is one that I can't provide a rigorous proof for.

---

*My unfinished proof (apologies for the nonstandard notation)*

We have $+(a, b) = \alpha \in G$, and $+(\alpha, c) = \beta \in G$. Translating to usual notation that is logically equivalent to $(a +b) + c = \alpha + c = \beta$

Now put $+(b, c) = \lambda \in G$, and $+(a, \lambda) = \zeta$. Translating to usual notation, that is logically equivalent to $a + (b+c) = a + \lambda = \zeta$

But I can't seem to think of a way to show $\beta = \zeta$, and I can't use any standard arithmetic to manipulate anything as $+$ is the only binary operation on $G$.

Comment: If the only thing we know about the binary operation is that it is closed (and, perhaps, commutative, since they chose to use $+$ as its symbol), then there is no guarantee that it is associative.

Comment: Notice that if $+$ were the usual addition, then it would not be closed. $1$ and $-1$ are in $G$ but their sum isn't.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, my apologies $0 \in G$, I forgot to add that in the OP

Comment: That does not solve the issue. Any rational $0<q<1$ can be written as a sum of $(q+1)$ and $-1$, and simillarly if $-1<q<0$ then it can be written as a sum of $(q-1)$ and $+1$.

Comment: All I meant with my comment, in any case, is that in spite of what the notation might point towards, thinking in terms of the usual addition should not help address this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not hold true in general. For a counterexample, consider the operation $\oplus$ defined as:

$$
x \oplus y = 
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
-x \quad \quad \text{if} & \;\;y = 0 \\
x \quad \quad \text{if} & \;\;y \ne 0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Then for $a \in G \setminus \{0\}\,$:

$$
(a \oplus 0) \oplus 0 = (-a) \oplus 0 = -(-a) = a \;\;\; \ne \;\;\; -a = a \oplus 0 = a \oplus (0 \oplus 0)
$$